# code modified lines added

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have data like this

```
date                    value
24sep2014 2:23:01        0.1
24sep2014 2:23:02        0.3
24sep2014 2:23:03        0.2
24sep2014 2:23:04        0.3
```

These are not coma seprated  value. I wanted to write in CSV file. Apend the value for next row.

1)How to open file only once here. when it run next time file name has to change to other name
2) How to append the next values

```
   Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Public Class Form1
    Dim myPort As Array
    Dim Distance As Integer



    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        PortComboBox.Items.AddRange(myPort)
        BaudComboBox.Items.Add(9600)
        BaudComboBox.Items.Add(19200)
        BaudComboBox.Items.Add(38400)
        BaudComboBox.Items.Add(57600)
        BaudComboBox.Items.Add(115200)
        ConnectButton.Enabled = True
        DisconnectButton.Enabled = False

        Chart1.Series.Clear()
        Chart1.Titles.Add("Demo")
        'Create a new series and add data points to it.
        Dim s As New Series
        s.Name = "CURRENT"
        s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line

    End Sub

    Private Sub ConnectButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ConnectButton.Click
        SerialPort1.PortName = PortComboBox.Text
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = BaudComboBox.Text
        SerialPort1.Open()
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer2.Start()
        'lblMessage.Text = PortComboBox.Text & " Connected."
        ConnectButton.Enabled = False
        DisconnectButton.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisconnectButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DisconnectButton.Click
        SerialPort1.Close()

        DisconnectButton.Enabled = False
        ConnectButton.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim counter As Integer
        counter = 0


        Try

            SerialPort1.Write("c")
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
            Dim k As Double
            Dim distance As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
            k = CDbl(distance)
            ListBoxSensor.Text = k

            Dim s As New Series
            s.Points.AddXY(1000, k)
            Chart1.Series.Add(s)

            Dim headerText = ""
            Dim csvFile As String = Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Current.csv")

            If Not File.Exists(csvFile)) Then
                headerText = "Date& time ,Current"
            End If

            Using outFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(csvFile, True)
                If headerText.Length > 0 Then
                    outFile.WriteLine(headerText)
                End If
                Dim y As String = DateAndTime.Now
                Dim x As String = y + "," + distance
                outFile.WriteLine(x)
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try



    End Sub

    Private Sub Relay_ON_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Relay_ON.Click
        SerialPort1.Write("1")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Relay_Off_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Relay_Off.Click
        SerialPort1.Write("0")
    End Sub




End Class
```

Here i am opening file again and again. that reason i can store only one value

@ steve error[image: Error image]

Comment: Read the docs about [OpenTextFileWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128023(v=vs.110).aspx), notice the second parameter? If True then Append, If False then Overwrite.

Comment: @steve i used true . It write one after the . but problem everytime it open it write "Date& time ,Current" and their value  gives space. next time same thing. I wanted date and time written only once and value one below other without leaving row

Comment: @steve is it possible to use counter inside the timer. For example i set timer interval for 1s if my count value==60 then only write to CSv file else only display the data??

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of [OpenTextFileWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128023(v=vs.110).aspx) allows to append instead of overwrite your file.
So it is simply a matter to check if the file exists (so you insert the header names) and then write your data

```
Dim headerText = ""
Dim csvFile As String = Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Current.csv")
If Not File.Exists(csvFile) Then
    headerText = "Date& time ,Current"
End If 

Using outFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(csvFile, True)
    If headerText.Length > 0 Then 
        outFile.WriteLine(headerText)
    End If
    Dim y As String = DateAndTime.Now
    Dim x As String = y + "," + distance
    outFile.WriteLine(x)
End Using
```

Notice the [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to be sure to close and dispose the file resource also in case of exceptions.

However given the simple text that need to be written you could also choose to use the method [WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128035(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dim headerText = ""
Dim csvFile As String = Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Current.csv")
If Not File.Exists(csvFile) Then
    headerText = "Date& time ,Current" & Environment.NewLine
End If 

Dim y As String = DateAndTime.Now
Dim x As String = headerText & y & "," + distance & Environment.NewLine
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(csvFile, x, True)
```

Comment: it gives error saying variable csvfile hidesa variable enclosing it.

Comment: it gives error saying variable csvfile hidesa variable enclosing it.also path/file  is not declared,

Comment: For the variable probably there is a double Dim somewhere not visible in the code above. For the Path/File you need to Imports System.IO to uses these classes.

Comment: As you can see in the error message, you have the option to Import System.IO just below the error message. (or if you don't like Import change to IO.Path.Combine(......) and IO.File.Exists(.....)

Comment: Thanks It worked. But it writing into csv leaving one row empty

Comment: That's the effect of WriteLine, it appends a newline after the write.