# Console Application: User entered date Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VS 2013 and VB language

My task is to store a user entered date in the format mm/dd/yyyy

```
    Dim date1 As String = Format("MM/dd/yyyy")
    Dim date2 As Date
    Dim date3 As Date

    date1 = Console.ReadLine()
    date2 = DateTime.Now
    date3 = DateTime.Parse(date1)


    Console.ReadLine()
```

I first tried entering the date as Dim date1 as Date, but entering it in mm/dd/yyyy is invalid format.

So I tried this method, and get the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

How can I format the entered date so that it will be recognized as a valid datetime?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

User cannot be forced to enter the date in the format that you expect (particularly on a console application). So your best line of action is trying to parse this date and inform your user that the input is invalid

```
 Dim isValid = False
 Dim dt As DateTime
 While(Not isValid)
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a date in the format MM/dd/yyyy")
    Dim input = Console.ReadLine()
    isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "MM/dd/yyyy", _
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dt)
 End While
```

[DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) is a method of the DateTime that tries to parse the input string accordingly to a format specified. If the string complies to the format required then the method returns true and the last parameter is set to the datetime resulting from the conversion. Otherwise the method return false without throwing an exception so you could take the appropriate measures (in this case request again the input)

Comment: Thank you Steve,
I recieve the error that CultureInfo and DateTimeStyles are not declared and my be inaccessible due to protection level.

Comment: If you look at the exception message you should see an `Import System.Globalization` link. You should add this namespace to get the Enumeration used in this method (A problem like this in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013105/code-modified-lines-added/26013694#26013694))

Comment: Thanks Steve that fixed all of my issues.  I had tried code similar to what you sent before and if I had known that was all I needed to do, I probably wouldn't have had to ask the question.  Your assistance sure is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

All dates are stored in memory as dates, and do not actually have formats. The formats appear when you change the date into a string (i.e. with the `Date.ToString()` method).

I think the best option here is to use `Date.Parse()` with no arguments, so that the command-line will accept all date formats (be prepared to catch format exceptions), and then when you need to display the date back to the user, format it using a format string and the `Date.ToString()` method.

Code example follows:

```
    Dim strDateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    Dim date2 As Date
    Dim date3 As Date

    date2 = Now()
    date3 = Date.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

    Console.WriteLine(date3.ToString(strDateFormat))
```

P.S. As you have it written, the command input overwrites your formatting string, so your formatting string is effectively useless.